# Locating Public Toilets in Europe

Tags: europe, hygiene

During my travels i often walk a lot and google has not been very helpful in locating Public Toilets.

Any there apps or maps available for locating Public toilets in Europe [Germany, Iceland, Czech Republic]?

Comment: Did you do a search on the site? As far as I remember we have had this question before, maybe specific on one or two European countries.

Comment: @Willeke: Yes i did, i can only find it for Taiwan.

Comment: UK answer (if it still works) here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73415/taming-the-nightmare-of-public-toilets-in-the-uk

Comment: I can also not find more. (And I often have difficulties and need to find public toilets.)

Comment: Hey, this was one of my shower ideas for an app! And here I thought it was a crappy idea....

Comment: Public toilets in Europe are not free, you have to pay 1 or 2 euros. Look for WC on street signs

Comment: @pbu, there are free public toilets, there are cheap public toilets, and there are those which are indeed €1 or might even (although I have not used one of those yet) cost €2. Some of them are well signposted, others may just be around the corner but impossible to find unless you have them on some sort of map.

Answer (score 15):

OpenStreetMap contains a database of points of interest and toilets are one of the categories of POI. Various apps are able to display these points or search for them. I just tested that in Osmand (a mapping app for Android) for the Czech Republic and there are many of them in the database.